# best way to store and update Data on device

Tags: ios, swift, storage

Every time, when user launches application, app sends request to `API` and receive `Data` from it. I have to storage old data in a file on device and update them with every launch. When size of Data will be over than 3-5 mb, reading can be very long, isn't it?
 My questions is: if i will store more than 5 mb of Data in file, can i quickly fetchs them, or only use database?
 If yes, how can i create directory and put file to it?
 And should i archive them?

Comment: Which type of data your are having?? And how did you tried?

Comment: Which type of data (images , string , videos ....etc) ??

Comment: I receive bytes, and store it. When i need to read them, i have to parse them into Int, String, etc

Comment: is there images too?

Comment: @MRizwan33, No, only bytes, which will be converted to Int, Double, String and other simple types

Comment: This bytes describes state of sensors, including temperature, humidity, chanel, time and other information. And I use this Data to drawing graphics of temperature, humidity etc

Comment: where are you storing them. mean in user defaults or realm right now?

Comment: @MRizwan33, Now i don't store them anywhere, only receive all data from api and read it, and it's takes so much time too. As i know, reading a lot of data from user defaults takes so much time

Comment: `reading a lot of data from user defaults takes so much time` Yes, this is normal, UserDefaults is absolutely not meant for storing data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar task and used CoreData with background fetch via DispatchQueue. I think this should help.

EDIT:

```
guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
        return
}
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {

    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "ENTITY")
    do {
        self."NSManagedObject ARRAY" = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
          }
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        //MAKING CHANGES TO VIEW
    }
}
```

P.S. I don't know how fast this fetch is, though it helped a lot in my task.

Comment: could you add some example of code, how are you used it? and how much Data are you stored? did data fetches immeditly?

Comment: I will try to use it later, and if it'll ask my question, I'll accept it